# How to update rows for one column based on string value of another? Python Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Planets': ['Mars','Mars','Mars', 'Jupyter', 'Venus', 'Venus', 'Mercury'], 'Rank': [1,np.nan, np.nan, 2, 3, np.nan, 4]})
```

I'm looking to update the Rank column (where there are nulls) based on the concurrency of the Planet entries. For example, where there are nulls after the entry '1' in the Rank column, we would populate the next two null rows with 1.

Comment: 'Jupyter' in a python question. Nice.

Comment: it is still a little unclear ? sample output would be nice

Comment: `fillna` should do what you need: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Comment: sorry! so the first three rows have a 'Planet' entry of 'Mars', however only the first row entry for 'Rank' is populated. I would like to take the relationship between 'Mars' and '1' and populate this where there are rows which have an entry of 'Mars' but a null entry for 'Rank'.. and so on down the dataset

Comment: Right, order by planet then by rank, then use `fillna` with the appropriate method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ffill](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) (forward-fill):

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   Planets  Rank
0     Mars     1
1     Mars   NaN
2     Mars   NaN
3  Jupyter     2
4    Venus     3
5    Venus   NaN
6  Mercury     4

In [12]: df["Rank"].ffill()
Out[12]:
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    3
6    4
Name: Rank, dtype: float64

In [13]: df["Rank"] = df["Rank"].ffill()

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
   Planets  Rank
0     Mars     1
1     Mars     1
2     Mars     1
3  Jupyter     2
4    Venus     3
5    Venus     3
6  Mercury     4
```

Comment: I was trying to remember if there was a groupby method to get this "Rank", another option might be to use a Categorical.

Comment: `groupby`-wise you could do `df.groupby("Planets")["Rank"].ffill()` or (what I might do, because it doesn't depend on where the non-nan value is) `df.groupby("Planets")["Rank"].transform(max)`.

Comment: @DSM the transform(max) trick is neat. Can you think of a way to get the 'rank" if you don't have it yet? like an enumerate for the groups? (like a sideways cumcount?)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the final result sorted by rank:

```
>>> df.sort(['Planets', 'Rank']).ffill().sort('Rank') 
   Planets  Rank
0     Mars     1
1     Mars     1
2     Mars     1
3  Jupyter     2
4    Venus     3
5    Venus     3
6  Mercury     4
```

A completely different approach would be to use a dictionary comprehension to map the unique planets:

```
df['Rank'] = df.Planets.map({planet: n for n, planet in enumerate(df.Planets.unique())})

>>> df
   Planets  Rank
0     Mars     0
1     Mars     0
2     Mars     0
3  Jupyter     1
4    Venus     2
5    Venus     2
6  Mercury     3
```

Comment: If the Rank is not sorted then the ffill most likely isn't going to work. :s

Comment: @AndyHayden It is the secondary sort after planets.

Comment: Ah, I imagined it as simply numbering the planets. It could be either with this tiny example :)